# How to build a robust system for scheduling notifications in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

**What I am trying to do**

Implement a multi user schedule management system. The idea is to allow user to set reminders and the system should notify them once it expires.

Currently, I can handle setting reminder, user talking to an endpoint, set a reminder for specific time and also multiple reminders, store to database -- using `sails.js framework`.

But my issue is that I need an automated trigger function that shoots the reminder once it expires.

- I looked at Node schedule but idea of pool of waiting functions doesn't seem to be the right way to do it .
- I was thinking some kind background job that runs all database and check against database , execute notification if reminder is due , but then huge problem on sending reminder on time , when it has crawl through all of them.

Thanks for advice

Comment: How many reminders are you talking about?  The nodejs timer system already does exactly what you want in a very speedy way, keeping track of a large list of times and triggering a callback for the next one.  But it is memory-based, not database-based so upon a restart of the server, you'd have to reread some persistent store to reset the timers.

Comment: @jfriend00 Is it good practice to make a check eg: `setInterval` every minute to check each user's reminders and check if their reminder has expired and then notify them?

Comment: No.  That would be quite wasteful.  It is more efficient to find the next reminder to fire and set a timer for that one and let the timer sub-system manage it.  When it goes off, you find the next reminder for that user to fire and set a timer for that one.  Then, you are not ever polling and you let the timer sub-system do what it's really good at.

Comment: @jfriend00 can I see an example about it? What if there are multiple scheduled reminders in a same date and time for every user? Hope you could show me an example :)

Comment: The code would be 99% about your data structures for storing scheduled reminders which you show us nothing about.  One simple algorithm would be find next scheduled reminder, set timer for that time from now. When that timer fires, find next scheduled reminder, if same time as last fire it now, otherwise set timer for it.  Repeat.  Any time new reminder set, check if it's before currently scheduled timer.  If so, cancel current timer, set timer for this new reminder.  If not, just store it, don't change current timer.